# Are status tables needed in Magento 2?

Tags: database, magento2.2, column

So I'm creating an admin grid and one of the fields is a dropdown select:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    //Here you can __construct Model

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        // return your data
        return [['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Option 1')], ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Option 2')]];
    }
}
```

I noticed that you can just pass a label and value without calling a status table, I initially created one with my module because I thought of usual DB design of using foreign keys to match it to a value in an options table, but this function `toOptionArray` makes that seem redundant.

So my question is, do I need those FK tables or is this enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do. Technically, the grid and form can function with hard coded values for dropdowns, but if you have dynamic values you need to use for sure a source model for them.